# Check the string from end that whether last character or word matches with the given key

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
function confirmEnding(str, key) {
    var a = [];
    var  ans = [];
    var b = a.length;
    if(b === 0) {
        ans=str.split("");
        if(ans[ans.length - 1] === key) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        ans=str.split(" ");
        if(ans[ans.length - 1] === key) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me correct answer for some example as `confirmEnding("Connor", "n")` but if I give example as `confirmEnding("He has to give me a new name", "name");` it give sme false instead of returning true. What is wrong in code?

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate what is wrong?

Comment: *Have you debugged it?* Before you post here, you should have tried to debug it. We aren't here to debug programs for people.

Comment: You are not splitting by a space in the first `ans=str.split("");`. It will split per character, so you will not have a match with *key* if *key* is more than one character. Also, `b===0` will always be true. What is the use of that?

Comment: @trincot i made an else condition for that.

Comment: `confirmEnding("this name", "ame")` should return `true` or `false`?

Comment: flase @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: So you are checking if the last word is equal to key right?

Comment: So `confirmEnding("this name", "that name")` should return `true` or `false`?

Comment: And `confirmEnding("this name", "this name")` should return `true` or `false`?

Comment: And `confirmEnding("Connor", "r")` should return `true` or `false`?

Comment: yes @ibrahimmahrir and `confirmEnding("Connor", "n")` should return false as I tried it to split by character so I was trying to make is else case if the input is string

Comment: `true` or `false`? for the other questions!

Comment: As `b===0` is always true the `else` part will never execute.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i just want to check last word(given string) or last character (given word)

Comment: Yes @trincot you are absolutely right I got my mistake as` a` array is empty but still I'm confused how to proceed with this.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir sorry for this , this should return true `confirmEnding("this name", "ame")`

Comment: One last thing is we passed a word then key must be a character right?

Comment: Yes @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: My old answer was correct! Wait I'll rollback to it!

Comment: ok @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: So `confirmEnding("name", "ame")` should return `false` because key is not a character? Make sure this time!

Comment: it should return `true`.

Comment: Ok I rolled back to my old answer. It was the right one from the beginning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.prototype.slice` given a negative number will slice from the end.

```js
function confirmEnding(str, key) {
  var last = str.slice( -key.length ); // get the last n characters of str (where n is the length of key)
  return key === last;                 // return true if it equal to key, false otherwise
}

console.log(confirmEnding("this is a name", "name"));

console.log(confirmEnding("this is a name", "this"));

console.log(confirmEnding("name", "big name"));
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly just i have little doubt with `-key.length` that how will it slice word?

Comment: @KedarKodgire If the `str` is `"abcdefgh"` then `str.slice(-2)` will be `"gh"`.

Comment: @KedarKodgire Here is the docs on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Comment: Ohk but in the case of `Connor` `-key.length` will be -6 right?

Comment: @KedarKodgire Yes! If `"Connor"` is passed as `key` of course!

Comment: @KedarKodgire When you pass a string `str` and a key `key` then we get only the last part of the string `str` that has the same length as `key` and we compare them! One thing you should note is that `"abc".slice(-2000) === "abc"` if the number is bigger than the string we just return the whole string that's why the last example in my answer return false!

Comment: one last doubt it, then `str.slice(-6)` is going to return whole word?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138422/discussion-between-kedar-kodgire-and-ibrahim-mahrir).